# VHDL "For" Loop Null Range

Tags: loops, for-loop, vhdl, hdl

I've been stuck at this problem for some hours now, and it seems I can't find the solution by searching i.e. didn't find anything here or on Google.

Here's my piece of code:

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.numeric_std;
USE work.arrays.ALL;

ENTITY parallel IS  
  PORT (clk:IN std_logic; text:IN INT_ARRAY(119 DOWNTO 0); result:OUT INT_MATRIX_2D);
END parallel;

ARCHITECTURE arch OF parallel IS
  COMPONENT unit_comparator IS
    PORT (letter:IN integer; difference:OUT integer);
  END COMPONENT;
  SIGNAL temp: INT_MATRIX_2D := (others => (others => 0));
  SIGNAL temp_differences: INT_ARRAY(119 DOWNTO 0) := (others => 0);
  BEGIN
    PROCESS(clk)
    BEGIN
      IF(rising_edge(clk))THEN
        FOR index IN 119 TO 1 LOOP
          temp(temp_differences(index))(temp_differences(index - 1)) <= 
          temp(temp_differences(index))(temp_differences(index - 1)) + 1;
        END LOOP;
        result <= temp;
      END IF;
    END PROCESS;
  wiring_loop: FOR index IN 119 DOWNTO 0 GENERATE
    wiring_unit: unit_comparator PORT MAP (text(index), temp_differences(index));
  END GENERATE;
END arch;
```

You see that "**FOR index IN *119 TO 1* LOOP**" ?

The compiler gives a "**Range 119 to 0 is *Null***" warning (no doubt the whole thing doesn't work as it should), which I seem to have a problem understanding. If there is an integer assigned to "index" at each step through the loop, how can it become null (and it says it happens at every step!). I need a firm understanding rather than a plain solution to this.
(Note: All of the modules and packages used are tested and work properly!)

Thank you!

Comment: The first Google hit (for me) on "VHDL null range" is [this nice explanation from Sigasi](http://insights.sigasi.com/tech/to-downto-ranges-vhdl.html). Your example is also not complete (because package `arrays` is missing) nor minimal (because of unneccessary components / instantiations).

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.2.1 (Scalar types): "A range specifies a subset of values of a scalar type. A range is said to be a null range if the specified subset is empty. The range L to R is called an ascending range; if L > R, then the range is a null range. The range L downto R is called a descending range; if L < R, then the range is a null range. L is called the *left bound* of the range, and R is called the *right bound* of the range." It's not an error, see 11.8 Generate statements, para 4: "The generate parameter is a constant object whose type is the base type of the discrete range ...".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ranges need a direction that corresponds to their limits. You want `119 downto 1` or `1 to 119`. `119 to 1` is not a range that is suitable for iterating through.

Comment: No need to say that you saved me (I need a new pair of glasses lol)

Comment: It's a perfectly valid range, it's just a null (empty) one!

Comment: @BrianDrummond is that better?