# For loop problem in architecture - vhdl. Making loop increment in architecture(not tb code)

Tags: for-loop, vhdl, clock, test-bench

i've got a problem with for loop increment in architecture, as i said no in test bench code. I wanted test any of 48 bit vecotr if it is '1' or '0' and then make something. It didn't work and i don't know what to do.

My code

wyswietl : process (clk, ZNAK_Z_ROM)
begin
if rising_edge(clk) then

```
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------

    for i in 47 to 42 loop

        if( ZNAK_Z_ROM(i) ='1' ) then
          if flaga='1' then
              flaga<='0';


                 vs<="1000000011";
                 hs<="0010010000"+conv_std_logic_vector((47-i+1)+(7*conv_integer(flag)),6);

          else


               vs<="1000000011";
               hs<="0010010000"+conv_std_logic_vector((47-i)+(7*conv_integer(flag)),6);

         end if;

        elsif(ZNAK_Z_ROM(i) ='0') then
            flaga<='1';





        end if;
    end loop;

            --------------------------------------------------------------------------

        for i in 41 to 36 loop

        if( ZNAK_Z_ROM(i) ='1' ) then
          if flaga='1' then
              flaga<='0';


                 vs<="1000000100";
                 hs<="0010010000"+conv_std_logic_vector((41-i+1)+(7*conv_integer(flag)),6);

          else


               vs<="1000000100";
               hs<="0010010000"+conv_std_logic_vector((41-i)+(7*conv_integer(flag)),6);

         end if;

        elsif(ZNAK_Z_ROM(i) ='0') then
            flaga<='1';




        end if;
    end loop;
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------

    for i in 35 to 30 loop

        if( ZNAK_Z_ROM(i) ='1' ) then
          if flaga='1' then
              flaga<='0';


                 vs<="1000000011";
                 hs<="0010010000"+conv_std_logic_vector((35-i+1)+(7*conv_integer(flag)),6);

          else


               vs<="1000000011";
               hs<="0010010000"+conv_std_logic_vector((35-i)+(7*conv_integer(flag)),6);

         end if;

        elsif(ZNAK_Z_ROM(i) ='0') then
            flaga<='1';




        end if;
    end loop;

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------


            for i in 29 to 24 loop

        if( ZNAK_Z_ROM(i) ='1' ) then
          if flaga='1' then
              flaga<='0';


                 vs<="1000000010";
                 hs<="0010010000"+conv_std_logic_vector((29-i+1)+(7*conv_integer(flag)),6);

          else


               vs<="1000000010";
               hs<="0010010000"+conv_std_logic_vector((29-i)+(7*conv_integer(flag)),6);

         end if;

        elsif(ZNAK_Z_ROM(i) ='0') then
            flaga<='1';




        end if;
    end loop;
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------

            for i in 23 to 18 loop

        if( ZNAK_Z_ROM(i) ='1' ) then
          if flaga='1' then
              flaga<='0';


                 vs<="1000000001";
                 hs<="0010010000"+conv_std_logic_vector((23-i+1)+(7*conv_integer(flag)),6);

          else


               vs<="1000000001";
               hs<="0010010000"+conv_std_logic_vector((23-i)+(7*conv_integer(flag)),6);

         end if;

        elsif(ZNAK_Z_ROM(i) ='0') then
            flaga<='1';




        end if;
    end loop;
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------

        for i in 17 to 12 loop

        if( ZNAK_Z_ROM(i) ='1' ) then
          if flaga='1' then
              flaga<='0';


                 vs<="1000000000";
                 hs<="0010010000"+conv_std_logic_vector((17-i+1)+(7*conv_integer(flag)),6);

          else


               vs<="1000000000";
               hs<="0010010000"+conv_std_logic_vector((17-i)+(7*conv_integer(flag)),6);

         end if;

        elsif(ZNAK_Z_ROM(i) ='0') then
            flaga<='1';




        end if;
    end loop;

            -----------------------------------------------------------------------

        for i in 11 to 6 loop

        if( ZNAK_Z_ROM(i) ='1' ) then
          if flaga='1' then
              flaga<='0';


                 vs<="0111111111";
                 hs<="0010010000"+conv_std_logic_vector((11-i+1)+(7*conv_integer(flag)),6);

          else


               vs<="0111111111";
               hs<="0010010000"+conv_std_logic_vector((11-i)+(7*conv_integer(flag)),6);

         end if;

        elsif(ZNAK_Z_ROM(i) ='0') then
            flaga<='1';




        end if;
    end loop;
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------

        for i in 5 to 0 loop

        if( ZNAK_Z_ROM(i) ='1' ) then
          if flaga='1' then
              flaga<='0';


                 vs<="0111111110";
                 hs<="0010010000"+conv_std_logic_vector((5-i+1)+(7*conv_integer(flag)),6);

          else


               vs<="0111111110";
               hs<="0010010000"+conv_std_logic_vector((5-i)+(7*conv_integer(flag)),6);

         end if;

        elsif(ZNAK_Z_ROM(i) ='0') then
            flaga<='1';




        end if;
    end loop;

    flag<=flag+"00001";

 end if;
```

end process;

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.2 Scalar types 5.2.1 paras 3 & 4 (in part): "A range specifies a subset of values of a scalar type. A range is said to be a *null range* if the specified subset is empty. The range L **to** R is called an *ascending range*; if L > R, then the range is a null range. ..."  Use **downto** where the L value in a range is greater than the R value. Your shown for loop parameters have null ranges.

Comment: Duplicate of [VHDL "For" Loop Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36499014/vhdl-for-loop-null-range).