# VHDL shift Array elements of an (N+1) x 13 Array

Tags: arrays, for-loop, vhdl

I seem to have problems with shifting vector array elements. When my FSM enters a state, a 0 should be added to the beginning of an input, which then is saved at the 0th array position. The rest of the array entries should be shifted one step further, so position 0 to position 1 etc.

What I tried to use in my statemachine is

```
when readAndShift =>
   x(0) <= "0" & x_in;
   for i in N to 1 loop
      x(i)    <=  x(i-1);    
   end loop;
```

The type and variable declaration is:

```
type    tap_line is array(0 to N) of std_logic_vector(12 downto 0);
.
.
.
signal x    :   tap_line  := (others=>(others=>'0'));
```

As far as I understood, in VHDL the for loop "unfolds" itself and executes every step of the for loop simultaneously, so one rising clock edge should be sufficient, right? My simulation only shows change in the 0th array element.

[image: Simulation]

Comment: Of course I will be happy to share the full code and also the simulation file, but I thought maybe I already got the shown code wrong

Comment: `for i in 1 to N loop`

Comment: @giampietro-seu rather not. 
`for i in N downto 1 loop`

Comment: @mfro what is the difference?

Comment: @giampietro-seu regarding the result, there is none. Regarding the learning effect, a lot.

Comment: @user1155120 Thanks for the input, I could have looked that up by myself, but I seem to be blind ;)

Comment: If you had searched with tags [tag:for-loop] and [tag:vhdl] you'd have found [VHDL "For" Loop Null Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36499014/vhdl-for-loop-null-range) with an accepted up voted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so what I wanted to write is

```
when readAndShift =>
   x(0) <= "0" & x_in;
   for i in N downto 1 loop
      x(i)    <=  x(i-1);    
   end loop;
```

I thought the direction would be determined automatically.
Thanks for the help, now I can continue with fixing the rest of the logical issues

Comment: You should be able to skip the loop and just do:
x(N downto 1) <= x(N-1 downto 0);

Comment: The type of x has an ascending order, Timmy Brolin's comment won't work. Try `x <= ('0' & x_in) & x(0 to N - 1);` where concatenation operators are predefined for any single dimensional array type (tap_line) and while lacking a [mcve] with the  declaration for `x_in,` it appears to be subtype compatible with std_logic_vector and have a length of 12.

Comment: Tanks for the comment, I will try it out, but the for loop works just fine for me.